# console.debug() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I noticed that the *console.debug()* doesn't always works as expected (at least in google chrome). For example, in the following code the *console.debug ( dirs )* works fine until the *alert ( dirs )* function works. But when I say to chrome to stop the alert windows from the page, the *console.debug( dirs )* begin to shows an empty array (*[ ]*).
If I print the array in a for-loop, however, I see it's not really empty.

```
var dirs = [ 0, 1, 2, 3 ];
console.debug ( dirs );
alert ( dirs );
```

The code is called through the

```
setInterval ( "function_with_the_code()", 20 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Chrome / Safari WebInspector, and Opera Dragonfly output *live* objects.

so, the code

`for(var a =[], i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { a.push(i), console.log( a ); }`

will output

```
Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
Array [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but,

`for(var a =[], i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) { a.push(i), console.log( a + '' ); }`

will output

```
0
0,1
0,1,2
0,1,2,3
0,1,2,3,4
```

Don't remember about IE F12, Firebug or Native Firefox Console.

Comment: I am sorry, but I still don't get why my static array doesn't show correctly, unless I put the alert()